# Should I test the Interface and All objects that implement it

Tags: unit-testing, xunit

Hi 
Assume I have an Interface A and a class B that implements A. Within my test class I create a dummy class that implements A and I "test the Interface methods" now my question is should I test the methods that class B "gets" from the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, you just test concrete classes and their interaction with interfaces.

That is, if you have concrete class B that implements A, you just test B and its interaction with other objects it references.

Comment: Hi I'm not too sure about this because if someone removes a method or property from an interface then all the concrete classes that implement the Interface, their tests will still pass...I think. In my opinion this seems incorrect.

Comment: If you are removing an member from the interface, and you are correctly using that interface as the type having actions performed on (as opposed to the concrete type), then removing a member will cause compilation failures. Say you have an `ISomething` interface and you are using that in code: `ISomething.DoSomething` will fail to compile if `ISomething.DoSomething` is removed, whereas if I have a type `MySomething : ISomething` and I'm using `MySomething.DoSomething` this will not fail because of its implementation in `MySomething`. I would ensure your code is doing the former. `ISomething`.

Comment: @user351709 I read your comment only now, but I agree 100% with Matthew. If you change an interface, you'll get failing tests where you *use* that interface's implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Generally testing should touch all (executable) lines of code. If you are implementing an interface it makes it that much easier, since you can code tests that form the "contract" of the interface and now the tests apply to all implementors of the interface.

This ensures consistency across all implementors. Should you encounter a situation where implementors behave differently (e.g. NullReferenceException vs. ArgumentNullException) you can add tests specifying which is "right" and which is wrong. This leads to less surprises down the road.

I might even go as far as saying that every interface should have a set of tests attached to describe the expected behaviour.

There are of course implementation specific things that can only be tested on the concrete implementor (e.g. "Was the file written?"  vs. "Was the record comitted?"). These things should be provided through overriding or lambdas to the interface's test suite.

Comment: Very interesting. How would I accomplish testing the the interface to describe its expected behavior.

Comment: Using NUnit: `[TestFixture(typeof(Implementor1))][TestFixture(typeof(Implementor2))] public class Fixture<T> where T : ITestedInterface { [Test]public void TestMethod(T iface) { Assert.That(iface, Behaves.Properly); } }` (http://nunit.net/blogs/?p=62) If your test framework doesn't support this you can emulate by making an abstract base class containing all tests and inherit from it, adding initialisation and the concrete types.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should aim to get 100% code coverage with your testing

Answer (score 0):

Since your interface shouldn't have any concrete implementation then you don't need to test it since there is nothing to test by definition. The testing should be for the concrete implementation of the interface.

If you find yourself in a situation where you need to have a partial implementaton of an interface you can do what I do. For instance, say I have a interface of an item. This I call `IItem` and has all the interface.  Then I declare an `Item` which is the partial implementation of the interface for common code and then `ItemA`, `ItemB`, etc. for the specialisations of `Item`.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying but I think I should "test the interface". I would like it to break a test when something changes because I wouldn't want someone to accidentally or foolishly remove a method. A test break forces someone (clever) to consider the changes made but I'm new to this so correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: But if you are removing a method from an interface that the concrete implementations still rely on surely you shouldn't be removing that part of the interface?  Since you can't prevent overloading you are pretty much stuck apart from adding a pragma informing users during build that they shouldn't be overloading that function .

Comment: I understand. If I purposefully remove a method from an Interface I can remove it and fix the test so it passes. My point was that "testing an interface" may be a valid because its an extra precaution. In my current company we had to test our get and set methods even {get;set;}. This stops us from doing something stupid which was accidental(it's a long story). If such a lame test is justified (and it is) I think that "testing the interface" is justified. Do you still disagree?

Comment: "Fix the test so that it passes". That is back to front. You should be fixing the code so that test passes or do you mean to make the test fail if someone has it implemented?  Also I still maintain that testing an interface is pointless as you have nothing to test. Also you can't prevent overloading, so you can't stop developers from implementing a function.

Answer (score 0):

I read all your posts I I think this solution works best.

```
Interface A
{
   String A1();
   String A2();
}

public class B:A
{
   String A1(){return "A1"}
   String A2(){return "A2"}
}

public class testB
{
   public void B_Can_Return_A1()
   {
      A b=new B();
      Assert.True(b.A1=="A1")
   }
}
```

> But if you are removing a method from an interface that the concrete implementations still rely on surely you shouldn't be removing that part of the interface?

This is true but this should still be enforced in tests i.e. tested. interfaces (should) play a big role in development and changes may create huge problems down the line. If an object implements an interface I think this is how it should be tested or something similar.

Please comment on this.